# JTA Synchronization and Timeouts

Tags: java, transactions, jta

When using the Java Transaction API (JTA) and I register a Synchronization with the current transaction, will the afterCompletion() method be called if the transaction times out?  If so, when will the afterCompletion() method be called, i.e. as soon as the transaction runs over the allotted timeout value or when the first operation on the transaction post timeout occurs?  What value will the status argument have (I assume it will be STATUS_ROLLEDBACK)?

Answer (score 2):

> When using the Java Transaction API (JTA) and I register a `Synchronization` with the current transaction, will the `afterCompletion()` method be called if the transaction times out?

The `afterCompletion` method is called *after the transaction is **committed** or **rolled back*** so it ought to be called after a timeout.

> If so, when will the `afterCompletion()` method be called, i.e. as soon as the transaction runs over the allotted timeout value or when the first operation on the transaction post timeout occurs?

AFAIK, if a transaction has not terminated (committed or rolled back) before the timeout value elapses, the transaction system will automatically roll it back. In other words, it doesn't wait for subsequent work on the transaction.

> What value will the status argument have (I assume it will be rolled back)?

I would indeed say `Status.STATUS_ROLLEDBACK` at the time of the `afterCompletion` invocation.